# mindmap problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

When compiling (on debian) the example in http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/computer-science-mindmap/ I get a strange behavior of the central node (see attached image). have you any suggestion ?

(I'm sorry it was a problem of my pdf viewer)
Regards,

Mohamed

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Perhaps you are running an old version. Debian comes with 2009 release I think, so if that is the case upgrade to the 2012 release (I'd recommend `TeXLive 2012`) and see if the problem persists.  It would also help if you provided details as to what exactly is the strange behavior.